# App Crashes While Scrolling ListView and Loading new data on Button Click event

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am using ListView in my application. 
ListView loads 10 data every time when it reaches its last position.
For that, I am calculating last position of ListView and when ListView scrolls to its last position I am loading next 10 data.

Now, the Issue is when I am Scrolling ListView and Clicked on Button that load data again app crashes.

NOTE : App works fine If I am not Scrolling ListView and Clicking on Active or Completed Buttons. It crashes only when I clicked on Active or Complete button while ListView is Scrolling.

My Code is as below :

```
 case R.id.btnCompleted:

            if (arrayListMy.size() > 0) {
                arrayListMy.clear();
            }
            btnCompleted.setImageResource(R.drawable.completed_selected);
            btnActive.setImageResource(R.drawable.active);
            filterFlag = "1";
            if (Common.isOnline(homeCustomerActivity)) {
                if (isAdded()) {
                    new MyAsyncTask("0", "0", getActivity()).execute();
                }
            } else {
                Common.displayToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.strErrorInternetConnection));
            }
            break;

        case R.id.btnActive:
            if (arrayListMy.size() > 0) {
               arrayListMy.clear();
            }
            btnCompleted.setImageResource(R.drawable.completed);
            btnActive.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_selected);
            filterFlag = "0";
            if(getActivity()!=null){
                if (Common.isOnline(getActivity())) {
                    if (isAdded()) {
                        new MyAsyncTask("0", "0", getActivity()).execute();
                    }
                } else {
                    Common.displayToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.strErrorInternetConnection));
                }
            }
            break;
    }
```

ERROR :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 17, size is 1
                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                           at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:225)
                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:671)
                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5048)
                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4595)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:775)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:588)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:557)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Please, Help me to solve out this.
Thank you.

Comment: could you please post your full code

Comment: Where is your  Active or Completed Buttons on Layout?